# Unable to install gnome shell in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, gnome, ubuntu-10.04

I am unable to install gnome-shell through Synaptic and am getting the following error. Can someone please help me out?

```
vmuser@vmhub:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gir1.0-atk-1.0 gir1.0-clutter-1.0 gir1.0-freedesktop gir1.0-glib-2.0
  gir1.0-gtk-2.0 gir1.0-mutter-2.28 gir1.0-pango-1.0 libgirepository1.0-0
  libgjs0 libmutter-private0 mesa-utils mutter mutter-common xbase-clients
  xserver-common xserver-xephyr
Suggested packages:
  gnome-themes
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.0-atk-1.0 gir1.0-clutter-1.0 gir1.0-freedesktop gir1.0-glib-2.0
  gir1.0-gtk-2.0 gir1.0-mutter-2.28 gir1.0-pango-1.0 gnome-shell
  libgirepository1.0-0 libgjs0 libmutter-private0 mesa-utils mutter
  mutter-common xbase-clients xserver-xephyr
The following packages will be upgraded:
  xserver-common
1 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 163 not upgraded.
Need to get 557kB/5,557kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.7MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libgirepository1.0-0 gir1.0-glib-2.0 gir1.0-atk-1.0 gir1.0-freedesktop gir1.0-pango-1.0 gir1.0-clutter-1.0 gir1.0-gtk-2.0 gir1.0-mutter-2.28 mutter-common libmutter-private0 xbase-clients xserver-common
  xserver-xephyr libgjs0 mutter mesa-utils gnome-shell
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main gir1.0-gtk-2.0 2.20.1-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+2.0/gir1.0-gtk-2.0_2.20.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to install version *2.20.1-0ubuntu1* of gir1.0-gtk-2.0 but the current version in lucid-updates is *2.20.1-0ubuntu2*

Run `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

Comment: Awesome... Works perfectly fine! Thanks a lot...